# Gatling index.html report not loading properly in AZure Devops after publishing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, gatling

**Image of the Gatling index.html report not loading properly**:

[image: Click here for reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the same issue when I publish the Index.html file in azure devops.

[image]

When I check the source code of the Index.html file, I notice that  this file needs to call the style from the style and js folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="style/favicon.ico"/>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gatling.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment-2.24.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/all_sessions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/stats.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/unpack.js"></script>
<title>Gatling Stats - Global Information</title>
</head>
```

When you only publish the index.html page , it cannot find the referenced style, so this problem occurs.

To view the correct content of the index.html, you need to publish the result as build artifacts in Azure Devops.

```
steps:
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven pom.xml'
  inputs:
    goals: 'mvn gatling:test'

- powershell: 'mvn gatling:test'
  workingDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.sourcesdirectory)/filepath'
```

[image]

Then you could download the artifacts to your local machine.

[image]

All in all, in azure devops, there is no method to load the referenced style in build tab(e.g. Published Html), so you can only download it locally for viewing.

**Update1:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, In my local as well am facing the same issue while opening index.html... Can you let me know where i can make changes to get the proper view of index.html

Comment: Hello, when you execute the test on your local, can you see the js and style folder in the same path? These folders are required.

Comment: Yes i can see that

Comment: In this case, it still couldn't work, right? What type of your project？ Based on my test, when the folder contains the required js and style file, it could work fine

Comment: I have downloaded the Js and Style in same folder and now i can see index.html properly loaded.. Do we have any other way?

Comment: I am afraid that  there is no method could achieve it in Azure Devops. Because we can only publish the pure html file (without js and style file) .  So you can only do it on your local machine via downloading the artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

This file is meant to be loaded from your local disk on your local desktop/laptop, not from a web server.

If you're looking for online reports for Gatling, you could consider [FrontLine](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/). It's also available on the Azure Marketplace.

Comment: From my local machine as well, am getting this kind of html...Frontline is not open source

Comment: Indeed, FrontLine is neither open source nor free. But neither is Azure Devops :)